# Angular + Firestore snapshotChanges update

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have probably very simple problem but I don't know how to solve it.

I have a function where I can get limit data with metadata like ID:

```
getLimitItems(page) {
    console.log(page)
    return this.afs.collection('movies', ref => ref
    .orderBy('titlePL')
    .limit(page)
    ).snapshotChanges().pipe(map( actions => {
      console.log('aa')
      return actions.map( a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Movie;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        console.log(data)
        return { id, data };
      });
  }));
```

Then thing is, when I call this function for the first time with argument `page = 1`, it works nice, but when I want to call it second time with argument `page = 2` it's not working.
First `console.log` print the argument but second one `'aa'` doesn't shows up.

My point is that I want to display data and default is 1 item but when I click on button with value 2 it's gonna display 2 items. I would use `get()` method but I need ID's also.